# Class and Trigger packageVersions elements missing in meta XML files using Force IDE

Tags: ide, metadata

Today two of my colleagues - one working on a na12 org and one working on a na15 org - have found that the meta.xml files that the Eclipse Force IDE pulls back for classes and triggers are missing the package version dependency element "packageVersions". They believe it was working earlier this week after Summer '13 had been rolled out. This is for several managed packages that we and third parties have created, and the problem is with the additional non-packaged code that we add for specific customers.

Has anyone else experienced this? Is it an enhancement (related to "InstalledPackage"?) or is something broken? If the latter, is there a workaround?

Comment: InstalledPackage is used to perform install and uninstall operations, my gut feel is that it is not related to this new feature and that this is a bug. I am interested to know if it is causing any other effects though, for example when you look at your package does it still list the other referenced packages as a dependency?

Comment: RE: The case I raised per my answer below. I just had a call from Salesforce support to say they are looking into it and are aware other customers have raised it. They will provide me an update tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I'll post here if I get anything back from support too.

Comment: Update from Salesforce, "I have replicated this behavior in my DE Org also, and getting similar results. As discussed on call, I am currently investigating the root cause of this issue i.e if it is a Known Issue or Summer'13 Release feature. So I will get back to you with my findings."

Comment: Fyi, last update (late yesterday) on our case "I have escalated your case to Backline support Team. They will contact you soon."

Comment: One comment (late yesterday) from a salesforce person: "We did clean up unwanted namespace references with the latest release". I'll persue this to understand their thinking: perhaps the idea is that you just get a compilation error if too early a version of the managed package the code is dependent on is present in the target org. Its also not clear to me why this change wasn't versioned.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I've got this "This issue has been escalated to our R&D team, to confirm if this is an expected change.". I am really not sure how inter Apex package versioning is going to work if this meta data is removed? There is also he fact that it appears still partially in the web ui as per my screenshot below. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_version.htm.

Comment: Latest salesforce comment: "We have recognised as an issue and have requested a priority 1 fix, I will provide you an update with a tentative release date as soon as I get it. Unfortunately since this is not an intentional change I will not be able to comment on the side effects of deploying. We are exploring alternatives and workarounds at the moment and will keep you updated on the same as well."

Comment: Excellent! Progress! :)

Comment: I've got a case update that the issue should be fixed and I should retry, will be doing so shortly! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now a "Known Issues" posting which is the best place to go to find out the status on the fix:

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SyD7AAK.

Comment: Amazing, I've been going back and forth with support to get an answer on this. The support rep I've been working with had no knowledge of this. A case of the right hand not knowing what the left is doing. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I suspect this was raised as result of the cases we created, there is no date on it to confirm though. I agree though, would have been easier to point us to this if it did already exist.

Answer (score 6):

**** UPDATE: 4th July 2013, Issue Resovled? ****

I now see this in my metadata XML file!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ApexClass xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>28.0</apiVersion>
    <packageVersions>
        <majorNumber>1</majorNumber>
        <minorNumber>0</minorNumber>
        <namespace>packagea</namespace>
    </packageVersions>
    <packageVersions>
        <majorNumber>1</majorNumber>
        <minorNumber>0</minorNumber>
        <namespace>packageb</namespace>
    </packageVersions>
    <status>Active</status>
</ApexClass>
```

Salesforce have listed the issue and fixed [here](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SyD7AAK).

One oddity still is that the Versions tab still shows this...

[image]

I'll feed this back on my case see if they can explain this.

**Original Issue Observations**

Yes there is definitely something wrong here.

I have two test managed packages installed and I created the following...

```
public with sharing class TestPackageMeta {

    private packageb__Sales_Invoice__c sinv;

    private packagea__WorkOrders__c wo;
}
```

This resulted in this, no references to the packages...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ApexClass xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>28.0</apiVersion>
    <status>Active</status>
</ApexClass>
```

However the strange thing is this, one reference to package a, but not package b....

[image]

Yet reassuringly Show Dependencies showed this...

[image]

I also checked that the package dependencies have not been affected and thankfully not...

[image]

I've also raised a case on our Premier support contract to see if we can get some traction on this, case number 09403195.

Answer (score 1):

I too have noticed this. Last week we started noticing it on na15, but not na14, but as of June 25, it is now occurring on na14 as well. I have opened a case with Salesforce for clarification on this. It sounds to me like our friends at Salesforce are rolling out some change to the meta-data API.

Answer (score 0):

This does seem to be an issue and are working towards a fix.

However if there is no dependencies it is working right as we had cleaned up unwanted package references.

Comment: Hi Vivek, I assume you are a Salesforce employee? Yes it has been raised before on StackExchange that the dependency information was always being included regardless of there being any dependency, once this regression is cleared up, this will be a most welcome improvement! Thanks for the update. :)