# When building a package with a dependency how is the minimum version of the dependent package determined?

Tags: managed-package, deployment

I've a managed package, which I'll call **Package A**, that has a dependency on another package which I'll call **Package B**. The *meta.xml* files for the classes in **Package A** have the *majorNumber* and *minorNumber* for **Package B** set with the highest value being **5.15**. The org where the build for **Package A** is taking place has a higher version number installed for **Package B**, in this case the version is **6.27**.

When **Package A** is built it is dependent on version **6.27** of **Package B** and not **5.15** as the *meta.xml* files in the **Package A** state.

Investigating this further, uninstalling/installing **Package B** to version **5.15**, and building another version of **Package A** with no code changes results in the newly built **Package A** being dependent on **5.15** of **Package B**.

What I'm wondering is what is the expected behaviour in these circumstances? Is the installed version of **Package B** in the build org used as the minimum version of that dependent package for deployments of **Package A**?

Comment: I couldn't find definitive links which is really what I'm after.

Comment: I'm working at a company that has ISV status, and even I am having problems finding anything on this. ISVForce Guide is silent on this topic, Google and Help searches yield no answer to this question. Logically speaking, it would make sense that an extension's minimum supported version must be the installed version, since the packager cannot guarantee that a field, class, etc would be available in an earlier version without checking each component against the base package.

Comment: The API verifies that classes/fields/etc.. are available when saving a class, in that instance it uses the verison specified in the meta.xml file. This means that before packaging the version set for a class has already been verified to work.

Comment: I think it's something more subtle than that. I think, in reality, the system should aggregate all referenced elements from the source org and determine the minimum version from each element (the source org knows the "first version" of each element, so this would seem logical). One observation I've seen is that if you have a package built for, say, version 6.27, and you try to deploy it unmanaged into an organization with version 5.15 installed, you'll automatically get an error unless you change the version for every element back to 5.15.

Comment: I've submitted a case to SF -- I'll update here once/if I get a satisfactory response.

Answer (score 5):

**Background to packageVersions in meta-xml files.**

Your observations about about the Metadata XML files are correct, they are used to stamp the intended version of the platform and any related managed package components the Apex code or VF page is dependent apone. Prior to Summer'13 this stamping was rather over the top and occurred on all classes and pages regardless of if they made component references or not. Fortunately this didn't extend to the upload process, where the true references drove the packages actual dependencies. Since Summer'13 the logic in the platform has improved such that it now correctly states only when components are explicitly referenced. This answer discusses this in more detail, [Class and Trigger packageVersions elements missing in meta XML files using Force IDE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13037/class-and-trigger-packageversions-elements-missing-in-meta-xml-files-using-force).

**When should the Version Information be Updated?**

I've checked the Metadata API developers guide and while it does go into some [detail](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_classes.htm), it only describes the values in more detail, not the implications of them. I've also reviewed the [ISV Guide](https://ffdc.my.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_packaging_guide.pdf), which references [Extension Packages](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=publish_extensions.htm&language=en) in a few places as solutions to building apps to support different org editions, product features and Security Review implications. The best information I've found is this, which talks about [Understanding Dependencies](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=about_dependencies.htm&language=en_US) and also this information from the web UI where you can edit the version, [Defining Apex Classes](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?err=1&id=code_define_package.htm&siteLang=en_US).

> Click Version Settings to specify the version of Apex and the API used with this class. If your organization has installed managed packages from the AppExchange, you can also specify which version of each managed package to use with this class. Use the default values for all versions. This associates the class with the most recent version of Apex and the API, as well as each managed package. You can specify an older version of a managed package if you want to access components or functionality that differs from the most recent package version. You can specify an older version of Apex and the API to maintain specific behavior.

It also goes on to say this...

> To aid backwards-compatibility, classes are stored with the version settings for a specified version of Apex and the API. If the Apex class references components, such as a custom object, in installed managed packages, the version settings for each managed package referenced by the class is saved too.

My expectation from my experience (we have developed a number of base and extension packages) is that the version information (like the platform API version also in this file) remains static unless you as the developer decide to change it and opt into new functionality provided by the base package/s.

This level control is critical to how the extension package interacts with the base package at runtime and at compile time. For example at runtime the base package can determine at runtime via [System.getRequestVersion](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_System_requestVersion.htm) what version the caller is expect it to behave like and omit execute of functionality not available at that time. You can read a bit more about this interaction [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_version.htm).

**Thoughts on your experience...**

So if the version of the base package was implicitly updated in your extension package metadata files by installing a more recent base package version into the extension package development org. Then this would take this decision out of the developers hands and risk regressions in the extension package as new features surfaced from the base package.

So what you have described feels a little like a bug, possibly a side effect of the auto dependency correction introduced in Summer'13. Though the other thought I have is that you said you uninstalled the base package and reinstalled a later version. In this case you must not have had any dependencies in your extension package i assume to be able to do so? If so then once you install the base package again and then made new references they would as per the docs above, default to the latest version of the package unless you explicitly set them to an earlier version.

Hope this lot helps! :)

Comment: I appreciate the detailed response, with links to docs. But the outcome I observed is a little different. The version of the base package in the metadata files is still the same, i.e. it still reflects version 5.15 as the minimum version, but the package will not deploy without version 6.27 being installed, so there is a mismatch between what the metadata files show and what actual minimum verison is. Since this was the build org I commented out most of the code to remove the dependency in the base package to allow me to uninstall/install an older version. Does that all make sense?

Comment: Let me do some testing in some orgs of my own on this, yes I think it does, but will need to get back to this later in my evening, will update then.

Comment: Anymore details you can come up with would be great! Thanks.

Comment: If you download all your files in your extension package org, are sure there is not at least one reference to 6.27 in any metadata file? When you say deploy, your saying your getting an error during install of your extension pacakge when you only have v5.15 of your base package installed in the target org? (Sorry I've not had time to reproduce this yet).

Comment: I performed a complete refresh from server and there was no reference to any version 6+ of the base package, highest was 5.15. The error is exactly what you said, during an install of the extension package when 5.15 of base is installed.

Comment: This is definitely starting to sound like a bug....

Comment: I think you might be right -- I'll see what SF have to say. I'll submit a case via the partner portal, it will be next week at this stage though.

Comment: I've submitted a case to SF -- I'll update here once/if I get a satisfactory response.

Comment: Hitting the same issue where Package B in your example was upgraded to 2.38...even though all my meta references are still to 2.21, it won't let me install my package in an org with a lower version of Package B. Support is telling me that installed Version of Package B creates that dependency even if your code still references an earlier version. Was that your final understanding as well?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue as well. I pushed on Support for documentation of the behavior that the OP and folks in the other answer have observed - that installed versions of base packages in the packaging org force a dependency on those versions. They finally acknowledged that there wasn't any existing documentation of this fact, and wrote and published a new [Knowledge Article](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Newer-versions-of-dependent-packages-are-showing-as-required&language=en_US), which says in part:

> In addition to requiring that the base package be installed in an organization, a given version of the extension package will have, as a minimum dependency, the version of the base package(s) that were installed in the development organization for the extension package at the time that the extension was uploaded.